# Google Postini Support

Tags: email, accounts, spam

I've just ordered Postini for a friend's business and like an idiot I have added the secondary email address with the wrong extention .co.uk rather than .com. I have got the credentials through for the server but it wont let me access the system, I've attempted to use the password reset but that either dosnt do anything or send the reset email to the secondary email account which I put in incorrectly.

My question is have any of you dealt with Google/Postini before or are you maybe a reseller of the service that could help me out? I have posted on the Support forums but so far its two days without response and 4emails later without response!

To sum up, I've ordered the service, paid for it but cannot access the system to configure it at all!

EDIT: I understand that Google Reseller's have the ability to bump my support request and escalted it, if there is anyone out there I'd appreciate some help as I have the Google Support Reference number :)

Can anyone help?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do not have a 1-800 support number, have your financial institution do a chargeback on payment. That should get you some attention.

Comment: I'm in the UK and my intial order isnt for $1500 so they dont seem to be very bothered! - It was ordered on a credit card so i suppose if push comes to shove!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customer support is sadly not one of Google's strengths.

There really is no way to speed up a response from them.

Comment: Maybe that's only true for certain subsets of customers. With our Google Apps EDU account we get quick replies and a phone number answered by a real, live human.

Comment: @James EDU gets different support once you're able to prove your district's identity to Google.  *Technically* Google Apps EDU is "free". Most of the Postini stuff is also no charge. We only pay for archival/backup services, per-user, and even then we can select which users.